Diffuse Bake Image Is Clear? [SOLVED]
I am trying to bake a diffuse texture in cycles for a planet I made in order to import it into Unity. I have followed several youtube videos, but nothing seems to work. It says that the bake was successful, but nothing shows. My texture is 4096x4096 px and it is made from a procedural shader. It is properly uv-unwraped and metallic is all the way down. I don't know any other settings that could be messing it up. I tried saving the texture to my computer, but it was still definitely completely transparent. I was able to bake some asteroids successfully a while ago, but for some reason, it doesn't like my planet.
Note the clear image texture in the bottom left of my workspace after baking

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.
[Edit]
I managed to bake it by starting a new project and copying my nodes by hand. Thankfully I didn't have too many. The fresh project let me bake it just fine. No idea what went wrong...
